# Div and input field side by side

Tags: html

This HTML should show the div then the input right next to it but doesn't.  It shows them on separate lines. What is wrong?

`<div style="display: inline; float: left;">Title </div><input id="event_title" name="event_title" style="float:right; display: inline; width: 441px;" onclick="clear_field_color(this);"/>`

Should look like this:

```
Title  [_____________________________________________]
```

But looks like this:

```
Title 
       [_____________________________________________]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be surprised with float:right, just swap the order of the elements, and it will work as desired! Input first, div second

```
<input id="event_title" name="event_title" style="float:right; display: inline; width: 441px;" onclick="clear_field_color(this);"/><div style="display: inline; float: left;">Title </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try adjusting the `line-height` of the `div`, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/Ddwuf/), but I'd say semantically a label would make more sense than a div.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the gap between the title and the textbox then just get rid of the `float:right`

Perhaps put a padding after the title e.g:

```
<div style="display: inline; float: left; padding-right:5px;">Title </div>
<input id="event_title" name="event_title" style=" display: inline; width: 441px;" onclick="clear_field_color(this);"/>​
```

Comment: There was no gap between the title and the input field.  The two elements come up on separate lines.  They aren't next to each other.

Comment: Perhaps you need to include the code that this div/textbox is sitting in.